# Redis Slave - Sending command to master in replication handshake: -Writing to master: Unknown error

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I'm a bit new to setting up redis sentinel but followed several online posts about it and it seemed fairly simple.  I'm getting the following error on any of my slaves when I start them up.  Below is the error and the configs on each machine.  They are all running Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and I have Redis 3.2.100 x64 installed.

**Node1 - redis.conf**

```
bind 127.0.0.1
port 6381

dir .
```

**Node2 - redis.conf**

```
bind 127.0.0.1
port 6381

dir .

slaveof 192.168.20.130 6380
```

Log output I'm receiving when I startup node2 (redis-server.exe node2\redis.conf)

```
26 Oct 18:27:33.889 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100
[1248] 26 Oct 18:27:33.889 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6380
[1248] 26 Oct 18:27:33.905 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 631464 bytes in use
[1248] 26 Oct 18:27:33.905 * Connecting to MASTER 192.168.20.130:6380
[1248] 26 Oct 18:27:33.905 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
[1248] 26 Oct 18:27:34.922 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
[1248] 26 Oct 18:27:34.922 # Sending command to master in replication handshake: -Writing to master: Unknown error
```

The firewall is off on both node1 and node2 and I can successfully ping between them.  I tested running node1 and node2 configurations on the same server and that works just fine so it seems to be going machine to machine.  Can't seem to find anything related to this error message.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error and finding some random forums it turns out you need to bind to your local IP address (not 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

I have added 127.0.0.1 and my local machine ip on both master and slave servre and it is working fine now.

on master 
bind 127.0.0.1 10.23X.XXX.XXX (local ip)

On slave 
bind 127.0.0.1 10.33X.XXX.XXX (local ip)